# How to create a response to an entity that has overlapping values (Google Dialogflow)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've been having trouble creating a response to a non-matched value within an entity in Dialogflow. I created a custom entity with a list of about 50 zip codes that trigger a response, but I need to make a response for a zipcode value that doesn't match the list.

I'm aware of @sys.zip-code and the functionality of it. My thought process is that the values within my custom entity overlap with the system's set of zip codes so the response would be the same for both.

If anyone has an idea on how to create a custom entity for zip codes that don't match my original list, it would be appreciated.

Comment: My general approach is that if you want to implement any kind of logic in DF, you have to use a custom fulfillment app. It could be as simple as a JS function, though.  I’m not aware of any way this could be implemented in DF itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fulfillment with your api, you can check the parameter against your list of zip codes. If the parameter doesn't match your list, send back an output context like "ZipUnmatched".

If you aren't using this method, you could go the more tedious route and add all of the zip codes to an intent. If a valid zip is entered, the valid zip intent will be triggered. Otherwise, prompt the user to enter a valid zip or do as you wish here.